# Raspberry Pi 4 network speed drop

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4, ethernet, modem

I configured my Raspberry Pi 4 to be a wireless and wired router that I can also use in combination with a D-Link DWM-222 USB modem. The problem is that when I connect the Ethernet cable (I am using a regular 10$ USB 3 Ethernet adapter bought from Amazon by the way) the performances drop from something like 16/17 Mbit/s in download (using Wi-Fi) to at around 3/4 Mbit/s maximum. I tried looking for undervoltages but I haven't been able to detect any problem related to the power supply or overheating, so is it just that the Raspberry Pi 4 is not capable of handling all these connections simultaneously?

Comment: It could be possible that is the case, the best I can get from my Pi 4 doing USB3 with HD connected to it for the transfer of a file is a rock solid 40MB/s off of it. Well under the 100MB/s I can see with regular machine. There is only one pci-e lane on the board for use by everything connected to it. Oh and the load on the machine goes from virtually 0 to well over 5-6 when it transfers and the temperatures rise a good 10-15C. It is working hard to get it done when doing it.

Comment: You have a Raspberry Pi 4B with a wired port and 4 USB ports. You use the wired port for the wired router, the wireless device for wireless and one USB port for the D-Link DWM-222 USB modem. For what do you need the additional 10$ USB/wired adapter?

Comment: Well the original idea was to use the Raspberry Pi as a sort of Wi-Fi repeater using the wired connection at home and only subsequently I decided to use a modem with it. Maybe I can try to use the embedded Gigabit Ethernet port but the problem linked to the USB connection still remains.